# How can I Remove registry entries on UnInstall (Install was done with Windows Installer)

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms

I have a small WPF application that writes some basic information to the registry during program execution.  The application is packaged with Windows Installer.  How can I tell the Windows Installer to uninstall registry entries that were created during program execution when the program is uninstalled through the control panel? (Also note, these entries were not created during the install.  They were created during program execution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will meet all of you needs, but it might help you look at it from a different angle.

Generally when I have to do something like this, I have the installer create "dummy" values for the registry values that the program will need. As a result, the program never needs to create a new registry value, and the uninstall process is trivial.

If I need dynamically generated registry values, I will generally have the registry value point to a folder in App Data, where I will use some sort of file structure. When doing this, removing dynamic elements is a trivial task (just delete the folder).

Comment: I like that Idea.  Quick question though.  Where in Windows installer would I create the "dummy" values.  I don't see an option for adding registry values?  I only see options to create folders and special folders.

Comment: Got it. Found the Registry Editor in VS.  Thanks.